# Problem with sql server and c# login while login shows System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name '0Stock.dbo.Login'.'

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Checking the username and the password 
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Stock;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * 
           FROM [0Stock].[dbo].[Login] where username='"+textBox1.Text+"' and passwrod='"+textBox2.Text+"'",con);
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtable);

            if (dtable.Rows.Count == 1)

                {
                this.Hide();
                StockMain main = new StockMain();
                 main.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!!","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Learn to use parameterized queries. Your program is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but I am fresh in sql will you tell me what it is the parameterized queries and it would be more helpfull if you provide an example.

Comment: Is `[0Stock]` a valid database?

Comment: I think this should work if you ommit the `[0Stock].` part.

Comment: Also, you are storing the password as clear text in your database. The simplest way to achieve better information security is to use [PWDENCRYPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to store and [PWDCOMPARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to compare.

Comment: No it should be Stock not 0Stock thank you very much it works fine!!!!!

Comment: Thankyou So much for your wonderful answers they help me alot.!